# QR code with http POST

Tags: http, post, qr-code

It's possible create a QR code that read an URL with some parameters in POST ?

Ex. QR CODE with URL GET : http:// mysite.com?cod=2

Ex. QR CODE with URL POST[cod]=2 : http:// mysite.com

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more? What do you want to do? You want to create a QR code, which will send an HTTP request after somone will scan it?

Comment: You could keep the parameters out of the GET request by putting them in the fragment identifier (after `#`), then process them with JavaScript as you wish. Eg `http:// mysite.com#cod=2`. They would still be QR code reader and browser history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

A QR code can only contain text - not instructions.

What you *could* do is have a script on your server which converts the `GET` into a `POST` - although I can't quite see why you would want that.

Comment: The data which should be in the POST parameter could be sensitive like a password. If you send it as GET parameter it will end up in the browser history and the server logs for example.